# Word problem about finding the inverse derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse, word-problem

I have the following word problem. I need to find and interpret the meaning of the inverse derivative of a function.

At a gas station, the function f(p) is the number of gallons of gasoline sold when the price is p dollars per gallon. The manager at the station measures and finds out that

f(2)=4023 and f'(4023).

I want to find f^-1(4023) and (f^-1)'(4023). Should I just use the general formula for inverse functions? I want to see the steps on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $y=f^{-1}(x)$ so $f(y)=x$. Now, using implicit differentiation:

$$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}f(y)=\frac{d}{dx}(x) \Longrightarrow f'(y)\cdot y'=1 \Longrightarrow y'=\frac{1}{f'(y)}\Longrightarrow (f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.$$

Comment: Ok, so I plugged in 1/f'(f^-1(4023)). Since f^-1(4023) is 2, I got 1/f'(2), which gives me 1/-1250. What does this mean in the word problem?

Comment: To clarify my question, I wanted to know what -1/1250 means about the sale of gas in the problem

Comment: @c0der Since the derivative gives us the rate at which the numbers of gallons are sold changes with respect to the price at $p$, the inverse says the rate at which the price changes with respect to the gallons sold. So at the 4024th gallon, we are expecting the price to be $1.9992 (since 2-0.0008=1.9992).